# Google Maps APIv3: Need to set it dynamically by postcode from the database

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, asp-classic, geolocation

I'm trying to install the new Google APIv3 Map for our [event pages here](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/events/2013/May/the-neil-diamond-story.html) (middle of the page).

The current map is the old embedded one and I can't get the new one to show.

I've got the API key and need to use a postcode parameter like the one currently:

```
          <div class="event-map">
            <iframe src="http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=<%=server.URLEncode(""&rs("ca_postcode"))%>&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=<%=Session("PublicFranchiseName")%>+<%=server.URLEncode(""&rs("ca_postcode"))%>,+United+Kingdom&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=near&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
        </div>
    <% end if %>
```

The following is the [code from Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple):

```
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
```

Here's the code I've tried, but doesn't work:

```
       <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <style>
              html { height: 100% }
              body { height: 100%; }
              #map-canvas { height: 100% }
            </style>

      <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?q=<%=server.URLEncode(""&rs("ca_postcode"))%>&hnear=<%=Session("PublicFranchiseName")%>+<%=server.URLEncode(""&rs("ca_postcode"))%>,+United+Kingdom&key=&sensor=false"></script>
            <script>
        var map;
        function initialize() {
          var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
              mapOptions);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

            </script>
```

Any help would be great

**Updated code:**

```
<div id='map-canvas'></div>
 <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?q=<%=server.URLEncode(""&rs("ca_postcode"))%>&hnear=<%=Session("PublicFranchiseName")%>+<%=server.URLEncode(""&rs("ca_postcode"))%>,+United+Kingdom&key=&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
var map;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var geolocate = function(address, callback) {
        $.ajax({
                url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json",
                data: {
                    "sensor": true,
                    "address": address
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(d) {
                    if (d.status == "ZERO_RESULTS") callback(false);
                    if (d.results && d.results[0] && d.results[0].geometry) {
                        callback({
                            "ne": d.results[0].geometry.bounds.northeast,
                            "sw": d.results[0].geometry.bounds.southwest,
                            "center": d.results[0].geometry.location
                        });
                    }
                    else callback(false);
                }
            });
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
  geolocate("<%=server.URLEncode(""&rs("ca_postcode"))%>&hnear=<%=Session("PublicFranchiseName")%>+<%=server.URLEncode(""&rs("ca_postcode"))%>,+United+Kingdom", function(c) {
        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(c.center.lat, c.center.lng));
 });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: This is a weird bug, as your code should, in theory, work (despite the fact that you do **NOT** set a lat/long pair by submitting a postcode in the URL like you've done. You'll need to geolocate using the geolocate API). I'll see if I can find anything.

Comment: Fixed the core bug. Adding geolocation for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have corrected your bug (which was due to the URI of the API) and added a geolocation call to the Google API for you. An example of your code is visible at the following address: http://tinker.io/95285

The geolocation call is done through AJAX. I have chosen to include jQuery in this fiddle. Replace the call with your usual AJAX library if you are not using jQuery. The geolocation API code is inspired off my demo code for the API [available here](http://blog.rescrape.it/index.php/2013/google-places-composite-queryes/).

If you have any questions, feel free to ask!

Please note that your API key is at no point necessary for what you are doing. Also, seeing as it is currently public, you may want to change it.

Comment: Hi there, thanks very much for the help. I'm not too familiar with customising it though and the only thing I have is the asp driven database postcodes - can we automatically calculate the lat/long with the code I posted above? Many thanks again

Comment: @suedarby: I have done exactly this. Look for "OX20BU" and replace with your database-driven postcode. P.S: that's my old postcode from when I lived in the UK. :-p

Comment: Almost there! Brilliant, I'll add what I've done to the end of the question if you could just have a quick look for me (and it can be seen under the old map on the page)

Comment: My geolocate function takes a non-URL-encoded address. jQuery does the encoding.

Comment: (@suedarby: can you give me a full address for testing?)

Comment: Great work and thank you for helping. I added the code above, if you could take a look at where I'm going wrong then we're there. Many thanks, that was a big help. Oxford is lovely :)

Comment: Yep it's: 15 Shenfield Rd,
Brentwood,
Essex,
CM15 8AG

Comment: @suedarby: Give exactly that string to the geolocation and it will work. Right now, you're feeding `<%=server.URLEncode(""&rs("ca_postcode"))%>&hnear=<%=Session("PublicFranchiseName")%>+<%=server.URLEncode(""&rs("ca_postcode"))%>,+United+Kingdom`, which Google Geolocate does not recognize (it deals with strings). Also, in the UK, a postcode is enough to uniquely identify a street, by the way.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite follow...which string?

Comment: That's the main part, the dynamically generated postcodes. The other one uses that and works fine, I just can't get it to work here.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, any chance you could have a quick check again for me? Still no further I'm afraid, you're my only hope! Please tell me which string I need to place & where..

Comment: Hi Seb, it worked when I changed the zoom! Thanks very much for the help - much appreciated. Is there a way I can invite you to answer another question that's map related? Many thanks again.

Comment: Hi just one question, do you know why I can't use the code twice on one page? One of them disappears when there's 2 maps...

Comment: @ig13: you will need to format your code in a modular fashion for it to work on multiple elements. For an example, look at the demo code link I supplied (the one to rescrape.it)

Comment: P.S: I'm travelling at the moment, so replies might be patchy. I'm in NC right now!